# how to filter array of objects with another array in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-leftpad-nzboku).

```
    const data = [
    { id: 1, serviceId: 1, title: "A" },
    { id: 2, serviceId: 3, title: "T" },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 45, title: "R" },
    { id: 4, serviceId: 55, title: "Q" },
    { id: 5, serviceId: 58, title: "S" },
    { id: 6, serviceId: 63, title: "zx" },
    { id: 7, serviceId: 66, title: "y" }
    ];

    const secondData = [55, 66, 1, 58];

    const myArrayFiltered = data.filter((el) => {
    return secondData.some((f) => {
      return f === el.serviceId;
    });
    });

     return (
       <div className="App">
        {myArrayFiltered.map((el) => (
          <div key={el?.id}>
           {el.title}-{el.serviceId}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
     );
```

I have `data` that should be filtered with `secondData` array.

The final result should be:

```
    { id: 2, serviceId: 3, title: "T" },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 45, title: "R" },
    { id: 6, serviceId: 63, title: "zx" },
```

for filtering, I wrote the following code.

```
      const myArrayFiltered = data.filter((el) => {
        return secondData.some((f) => {
          return f === el.serviceId;
     });
```

But it's returning the following:

```
   {id: 1, serviceId: 1, title: "A" },
   { id: 4, serviceId: 55, title: "Q" },
   { id: 5, serviceId: 58, title: "S" },
   { id: 7, serviceId: 66, title: "y" }
```

how can I fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: according to your logic, you are getting the correct data, because you are comparing your data with [55, 66, 1, 58]. try to compare it with [3, 45, 63].
Or try to use !== operator to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need `Array#some`. You could simply use `Array#includes` instead, to check whether current `serviceId` is or is not in the `secondData` array.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, serviceId: 1, title: "A" },
    { id: 2, serviceId: 3, title: "T" },
    { id: 3, serviceId: 45, title: "R" },
    { id: 4, serviceId: 55, title: "Q" },
    { id: 5, serviceId: 58, title: "S" },
    { id: 6, serviceId: 63, title: "zx" },
    { id: 7, serviceId: 66, title: "y" }
];


const secondData = [55, 66, 1, 58];

const myArrayFiltered = data.filter((el) => !secondData.includes(el.serviceId));

console.log(myArrayFiltered);
```